# Rake spec fails with: command terminated with exit code 137

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kubernetes, rspec, rspec-rails

I've a Rails app running in Kubernetes and try to run `bin/rake spec`
via `exec` in my running pod.

`kubectl exec backend-xxxxx -- sh`
`bin/rake -T` # lists my tasks (and works)
Other commands like `rake db:migrate` are working.

Now I try to run my specs, but equally what I try (using suite, models only or a single file) my pod crashes:

`bin/rake spec`

`bin/rake spec:models`

`bin/rake spec spec/models/user_spec.rb`

Output of rake task:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 119
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I/usr/local/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib:/usr/local/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-support-3.10.2/lib /usr/local/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
command terminated with exit code 137
```

This is my complete log:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.7.2-p137), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
Rails Version & environment: 6.1.4.1 - development
Elastic URL credentials provided
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Exiting with code 137 # <<<<<<----- this line appears when running rake spec
```

I've no idea why that happens. My Minikube has 12GB of assigned RAM (`minikube config set memory 12288`)

Comment: 1. use `--trace`

2. can you run from the pod? if that's possible.

Comment: got it working by `bundle exec rspec spec`

Comment: Don't know why rake fails